# Magento 2.0, MSSQL set up

Tags: magento2, database

I have read through a document from an external source, which says `magento 2.0` support MsSQL. Is this correct ? Link given below.

```
https://firebearstudio.com/blog/magento-2.html
```

However, when i set up magento 2.0 through installation wizard. I don't see an option to choose MsSQL. Also, when i give the MsSQL credentials, it will result me in error as following

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server
```

My Question is, will magento 2.0 support MsSQL for the core magento tables. If yes, what's the flow to install ?

Will it work for community edition ? OR is it for enterprise edition ?

Let us know on this please.

Answer (score 2):

Any such information is incorrect. Magento 2 (including 2.0, 2.1) does not support any database engine other than MySQL. No MsSQL, no PostgreSQL, no Oracle.

It might be theoretically possible, but it would require substantial customization or changes, and you would be running an entirely unsupported platform at that point.

Magento has not announced any plans to change this.